# How to make specific text bold in rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make bold specific line or string in a rich text box.

For Example:

```
string str = "Hello World";
string str1="Hello Everyone";

richtextbox1.text = str+str1 ;
```

Here i want "Hello world " in bold case, while "Hello Everyone" in regular case.

There is lot of code to make entire textbox bold.

`richtextbox1.Rtf`  is not working in for each loop as it's not giving bold text.

Answer (score 1):

[**Formatting Characters in Bold in a RichTextBox Control (Visual C#)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287595(v=vs.71).aspx)

You can use `Rtf` property

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi \b" + str + "\b0" + str1 + "}";
```

Comment: its showing error in this syntax